# How to fix the css red notification bubble

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Html Like follows which I created using twitter bootstrap.

```
<div class="row-fluid" style="padding-top:10px;">
    <div class="noti_bubble"><@= friendRequestCollection.size() @></div>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <i class="icon-eye-open icon-white"></i>
          <span class="caret"></span> 
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <@ friendRequestCollection.each(function(user) { @>
            <li id="user-list-<@= user.get('username') @>"><a href="#"><@= user.get('firstName') @></a></li>
        <@ }); @>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

I am trying to create a red notification bubble on the eye icon but its not looking so good.

My css for notification bubble.

```
.noti_Container {
position: relative;
/* This is just to show you where the container ends */
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
  }

  .noti_bubble {
position: absolute;
top: 2px;
right: 10px;
background-color: red;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 14px;
border-radius: 2px;
}
```

What i wanted is like hide the small arrow created by bootstrap with the red bubble and when the number increase in the bubble the bubble size must increase right side. Currently its increasing on left side so if the number inside the bubble is 100 for example so the whole eye icon becomes hidden with the bubble.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Position your badge with `left` instead of `right`:

```
.noti_bubble {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;

    /* this will anchor your badge from its left-hand edge at the midpoint of your icon */
    left: 8px;

    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Comment: @SaurabhKumar You can specify it explicitly by giving `height` a non-`auto` value or leave it as `auto` and tweak `font-size` and/or `line-height`. From your included screenshot it looks like you just need to reduce the `font-size`.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the increasing issue, just change the .noti_bubble CSS to this:

```
.noti_bubble {
   position: relative;
   display:inline-block;
   top: 2px;
   left: 25px;
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 14px;
   border-radius: 2px;
}
```